# range operator '...' instead of '..' It works

Tags: perl

I experimented a simple program in perl, with the range operator.

```
           eg: my @array = (1..100) ;
                print "@array\n"
```

This printed the 1 to 100 values in the array, but Instead of `..` if I give the `...` Even though the values from 1 to 100 was printed.

But more than 3 `.` was ignored and error was thrown.

I want to know that why the `...` was valid and how I got the correct output?

Comment: What do you mean by "correct output"?

Comment: @choroba it is printing from 1 to 100 values.

Comment: [perl 3 dot operator example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11021512/4248931)

Comment: Perhaps [Dots and Perl](http://perlhacks.com/2014/01/dots-perl/) will be interesting or useful.

Comment: huh, 4 dots doesn't cause an error. `perl -e'my @array = (1....100); print "@array\n"'` prints nothing because it's parsed as `1 ... .100`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`..` and `...` are different opperators:

[See here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators)

> In scalar context, ".." returns a boolean value. The operator is
>   bistable, like a flip-flop, and emulates the line-range (comma)
>   operator of sed, awk, and various editors. Each ".." operator
>   maintains its own boolean state, even across calls to a subroutine
>   that contains it. It is false as long as its left operand is false.
>   Once the left operand is true, the range operator stays true until the
>   right operand is true, AFTER which the range operator becomes false
>   again. It doesn't become false till the next time the range operator
>   is evaluated. It can test the right operand and become false on the
>   same evaluation it became true (as in awk), but it still returns true
>   once. If you don't want it to test the right operand until the next
>   evaluation, as in sed, just use three dots ("...") instead of two. In
>   all other regards, "..." behaves just like ".." does.

Comment: That part of the documentation is irrelevant except for the final sentence. In list context, as the OP has it, the two operators are identical

Answer (score 4):

The difference between `..` and `...` is noticable only in scalar context, when used as a flip-flop. See *Range Operators* in [perlop](http://p3rl.org/perlop):

> If you don't want it to test the right operand until the next evaluation,
>          as in sed, just use three dots ("...") instead of two.  In all other regards, "..." behaves just like ".." does.